# Tabs redirect to different page

Tags: views, 8

I'm building a job directory.

This will allow users to register, create Companies and Jobs associated with those companies.

A Job can be from one of the following types: Full-time, Part-time, Freelance and Internship.

The current Jobs View can be seen [here](http://jobdirectory.tiagoperes.eu/jobs):
[image]
It was created using Views, [just like in this video](https://youtu.be/hpuRdzyK3jI) and looks like this on the back:
[image]
**My current problem is** anytime a tab is clicked, the user goes to a completely different page, requiring the page to load again.
I don't want the user to go to a different page anytime they select a type of job...

Unsure how to do this using Drupal but I were to do this manually, would use Ajax and PHP so that the data could be retrieved from the DB and the page wouldn't require to load again.

[Drupal Legoland builds tabs using Field Group Module](https://youtu.be/P5WhIMofOEE). This looked like a good technique and easy to implement, but for my case doesn't really work as I don't have a specific field in the content type Jobs just with the Full-time Jobs Data and not sure how to create it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a module called [Quick Tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs), which allows to create Ajax loaded tabs. We need to flush all caches after creating the new tab in order to be seen as a normal block. It fixed the problem.